# How to fix the order of columns in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Hi I have a dataframe in which I have to fix the order of columns. I have a list in which prefix of column name defined. I have the fix the according to that list.

Example:

df Columns :-

```
nOffered_count, nOffered_sum, nTransferred_count, nTransferred_sum, tacd_count, tacd_sum, tacw_count, tacw_sum, tHeld_count, tHeld_sum
```

I have a list -

```
list = ['nOffered', 'tacw', 'tacd', 'nTransferred', 'tHeld']
```

In result I want below order in dataframe:

```
nOffered_count, nOffered_sum, tacw_count, tacw_sum, tacd_count, tacd_sum, nTransferred_count, nTransferred_sum, , tHeld_count, tHeld_sum
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create dictionary for ordering in enumerate and then sorting values before `_` by mapping this dictionary:

```
L = ['nOffered', 'tacw', 'tacd', 'nTransferred', 'tHeld']
d = {v: k for k, v in dict(enumerate(L)).items()}

cols = sorted(df.columns, key = lambda x: d.get(x.split('_')[0], ''))
print(cols)
['nOffered_count', 'nOffered_sum', 'tacw_count', 'tacw_sum', 
 'tacd_count', 'tacd_sum', 'nTransferred_count', 'nTransferred_sum', 
 'tHeld_count', 'tHeld_sum']
```

Last change order in `DataFrame`:

```
df = df[cols]
```

Another idea:

```
df = df.sort_index(key = lambda x: x.str.split('_').str[0].map(d).fillna(''), axis=1)
print(df)
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [nOffered_count, nOffered_sum, tacw_count, tacw_sum, 
          tacd_count, tacd_sum, nTransferred_count, nTransferred_sum, 
          tHeld_count, tHeld_sum]
Index: []
```